# Fileupload from AngularJs to laravel(Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string)

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting an issue with the file upload from angular to laravel 5.2. Throws an error of "*Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string*"

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('fileupload', array('as' => 'fileupload.index', 'uses'=>'FileController@index'));
Route::post('filehandler/submit', array('as' => 'filehandler.submit', 'uses' => 'FileController@store'));
```

**View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div  ng-controller="fileCtrl">
<form ng-submit="addList1()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="info.text">
  <input type="file" name="file" ng-model="info.file" id="uploads" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('/')}}/angular/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('/')}}/angular/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('/')}}/angular/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('/')}}/angular/js/all.js"></script>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use View;
use File;
use DB;

class FileController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return View('file');
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
$input = Input::all();

    $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
    $file = $input['file'];
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension;
    $file= Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    print_r($file);    
    exit;
}
}
```

**My JS file(all.js)**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
myApp.service('data', function ($http) {
var service ={};
service.postFile = function(info){
    var promise = $http.post('filehandler/submit', info);

    promise.then(function(response){
        angular.extend(info, response.data);
    });

    return promise;
};
return service;
})
.controller('fileCtrl', function($scope, data) {
$scope.info = {
    "text": "",
    "file": []
};
$scope.addList1 = function(form){            
    data.postFile($scope.info).then(function(response){
    console.log("hello", $scope.info);
    });             
};
})
```

It is working fine without angular, when I am implement through angular it shows error in my controller. In *FileController* I am getting an error "*Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string*". Can anyone please help me it to fix this out, Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "dd($input['file']);" return?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo It returns my uploaded file name "bg_piece.jpg"

Comment: I guess you need to create a directive. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534497/file-upload-using-angularjs-with-php-server-script. You still need to adapt to laravel.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the uploaded file you need to call Request's **file()** method.

Replace

```
$file = $input['file'];
```

with

```
$file = $request->file('file');
```

Comment: It returns null value